# C++: what regex library should I use?

Tags: c++, regex, linux

I'm working on a commercial (not open source) C++ project that runs on a  linux-based system.  I need to do some regex within the C++ code.  (I know:  I now have 2 problems.)

QUESTION:  What libraries do people who regularly do regex from C/C++ recommend I look into?  A quick search has brought the following to my attention:

1) Boost.Regex (I need to go read the Boost Software License, but this question is not about software licenses)

2) C (not C++) POSIX regex (#include <regex.h>, regcomp, regexec, etc.)

3) http://freshmeat.net/projects/cpp_regex/  (I know nothing about this one; seems to be GPL, therefore not usable on this project)

Comment: In case anyone is looking at this old question for hints...a new library has shown up recently that deserves to be mentioned:  Google's RE2:  http://code.google.com/p/re2/

Comment: [This](https://github.com/jpcre2/jpcre2) is a c++ wrapper for the new PCRE2 (revised version of PCRE) library.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions.

I tried out a few things today, and with the stuff we're trying to do, I opted for the simplest solution where I don't have to download any other 3rd-party library.  In the end, I #include <regex.h> and used the standard C POSIX calls regcomp() and regexec().  Not C++, but in a pinch this proved to be the easiest.

Answer (score 82):

[Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/libs/regex/) is very good and is slated to become part of the C++0x standard (it's already in TR1).

Personally, I find [Boost.Xpressive](http://www.boost.org/libs/xpressive/) much nicer to work with. It is a header-only library and it has some nice features such as static regexes (regexes compiled at compile time).

**Update:** If you're using a C++11 compliant compiler (gcc 4.8 is NOT!), use [std::regex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) unless you have good reason to use something else.

Comment: A project I was personally involved with had to switch from Boost.Regex to PCRE because of binary compatibility issues (Boost's non-header-only libraries tend to suffer from inexplicable ABI breakage with minor releases and/or compiler option changes).  However, if it's been absorbed into the C++ standard library that should cease to be a problem.

Comment: Boost is full of bugs and appears to lack a coding standards and QA process. Its not really suitable for production software. That includes its Regex gear, which uses C (rather than C++) in places and includes buffer overflows due to unsafe functions such as sprintf. When I reported a bunch of bugs after an audit, they remained "unacknowledged" months after the report. Use at your own risk.

Comment: `std::regex` isn't available in `libstdc++` yet so I fall back to posix regex.

Comment: Almost 5 years later, I tried today to use std::regex, but it turns out it hasn't yet been implemented in GCC.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671536/why-does-this-c11-stdregex-example-throw-a-regex-error-exception

Comment: that good reason not to use std::regex or boost::regex for that matter  would be that boost::regex, is around 10 times slower than re2

Comment: std::regex is still not complete - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12665408/452090

Comment: @jww Your comments are silly. sprintf does not necessarily demand a buffer overflow; it's entirely possible to use it and not have one occur, unlike (for example) gets. As well, boost is not "full of bugs"; while the occasional one crops up (as shown in it's changelog), it is no more than any other large scale project. As for a lack of coding standards or QA process, that's categorically wrong, as a simple google search would show. Given boost has been absorbed into the standard itself, I would suggest your comments are not merely untrue, but categorically so.

Comment: @Alice - I'm not a FanBoi, so I don't share you enthusiasm. I actually performed the audit, and the overflow was there plain as day. Two of them if I recall correctly. If Boost had a mature engineering process, then it likely would have been caught during review at checkin.

Comment: *"Given boost has been absorbed into the standard itself..."* - I'm not sure what that means. But if it means Boost's implementation is a reference implementation, then it probably means its unaudited (and probably broken somewhere).

Comment: @jww No, the C++ standard (C++03 TR, C++11 and C++1y) has decided to [incorporate several boost libraries into the standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/library_technical_report.html). That means, for all practical purposes, Boost *made* the standard. Making assertions without evidence using weasel words like "probably" and using personal attacks do nothing to change the fact that large parts of boost are now C++, and many of the people defining the modern direction of C++ are also working on boost.

Comment: @Alice - The C and C++ committees create standards. They don't incorporate libraries. I'm not aware of them ever producing a library.

Comment: @jww [Except they did](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/library_technical_report.html)

Comment: @Alice - Please show me a C or C++ library produced by the committee with Boost code in it. It does not have to uptake all Boost code; just some Boost code will be fine.

Comment: @jww [I already have three times now](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/library_technical_report.html)

Answer (score 20):

In C++ projects past, I have used [PCRE](http://pcre.org) with good success. It's very complete and well-tested since it's used in many high profile projects. And I see that Google has contributed a set of C++ wrappers for PCRE recently, too.

Answer (score 16):

C++ has a builtin regex library since TR1. AFAIK Boost's regex library is very compatible with it and can be used as a replacement, if your standard library doesn't provide TR1.

Comment: What compiler has TR1?  My copy of g++ 4.1.2 (Debian Etch) does not  have support for #include <regex> but thanks for bringing TR1 to my attention, I had forgotten.

For others curious to know more on TR1 and C++0x, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_Report_1

Comment: As of SP1 Visual Studio 2008 has most of TR1, including regex.  I know it doesn't help you on Linux, but others may be interested.  Dinkumware also supports TR1 on gcc.

Comment: As I wrote, if your std library doesn't have regex, then you can use boost: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost_tr1/subject_list.html#boost_tr1.subject_list.regex

Comment: g++ 4.5.0.  TR1 lives in tr1/regex.  e.g.: #include <tr1/regex>

Answer (score 11):

Boost has [regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html)  in it.

That should fill the bill

Comment: Also appears to be slower than Googles Re2 http://lh3lh3.users.sourceforge.net/reb.shtml

Answer (score 11):

Two more options:

If you can write it in **c++11** - Do the tutorial: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c15339

Note:
At the time of writing the only c++11 regex library that I know works is the [clang/llvm one](http://libcxx.llvm.org/), and only works on Mac. The GNU still [doesn't implement regex yet](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011). I don't know about Visual Studio. Most people still use the [boost regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) implementation.

---

Or you can use **ragel** to generate a finite state machine to do the parsing for you, and  generate the C/C++ code implementation: http://www.complang.org/ragel/

I used it a little to generate code to parse json. This ragel file: https://github.com/matiu2/yajp/blob/master/parser/number.rl
is used to generate this code
https://github.com/matiu2/yajp/blob/master/parser/json.hpp#L254
and this finite state machine diagram:

[image: state diagram]

---

**Update 1:**

lvm's libc++ regex works on ubuntu 14.04: libc++-dev - LLVM C++ Standard library (development files). When compiling: `clang++ -std=c++11 -lc++ -I/usr/include/c++/v1 ...`

**Update 2:**

I'm currently enjoying **[boost spirit 3](http://ciere.com/cppnow15/x3_docs/)** - I like it more than regex, because it has BNF style rules and is well thought out. (Older (more documented) Spirit Qi libs [found here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html))

Answer (score 7):

You can also look at [fast regex library](https://github.com/dprokoptsev/pire) that was developed at [Yandex](http://yandex.com) search engine for doing fast matches of thousands of patterns against huge amounts of data.

Answer (score 6):

I've personally always used boost.regex (although I don't have much need for regex in C++). Microsoft Labs has a regex library too, called GRETA: http://research.microsoft.com/projects/greta/. Apparently it's very fast and features a whole Perl 5 syntax. I haven't used it, but you may want to test it out.

Comment: GRETA (http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/bd99f343-4ff4-4041-8293-34c054efe749/default.aspx) was made by Eric Niebler when he worked at Microsoft (1998-2001 from GRETA's header files). Eric Niebler then made in 2007 Boost.Xpressive. 

People should use Boost.Xpressive because it's newer and has a nicer license than "Microsoft Research end user license agreement"

Comment: Sorry, I dont see how pulling in the Boost library is a good thing. The last time I checked the local download uncompressed version of boost is 400 megs. Not to mention the inain template madness you get with boost. Sorry, I recommend Gregs answer.

Comment: http://lh3lh3.users.sourceforge.net/reb.shtml

Comment: @Chad Because boost is a well known and well regarded set of standard libraries that are helpful in many situations? If the download size is too big for you, just use BCD to strip anything you don't need; boost.regex is quite small when stripped in this manner.

Answer (score 4):

I faced a similar situation and ended up using Henry Spencers Regexp Engine
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/spencerregexp.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Noone here said anything about the one that comes with C++0x.
If you are using a compiler and the STL that supports C++0x you could just use that instead of having another lib in your project.

Comment: If you look at the highest-voted answer (from 2+ years ago), it mentions this.