# How can we efficiently read only integers from text file in C#

Tags: c#, stream, text-files

In C++, we can define a custom locale that enables stream object to ignore non-digits in the file, and reads only the integers.

Can we do something similar? How can we efficiently read only integers from a text file? Does C# stream object use locale? If yes, can we define custom locale that we can use with stream object so as to ignore unwanted characters while reading the file?

---

Here is one example in C++ which efficiently counts frequency of words in a text file:

[Elegant ways to count the frequency of words in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888879/elegant-ways-to-count-words-in-a-file-in-c)

Comment: Maybe, if this is possible, you could use Managed C++ to perform the task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My proposal:

```
            public void ReadJustNumbers()
            {
                Regex r = new Regex(@"\d+"); 
                using (var sr = new StreamReader("xxx"))
                {
                    string line;
                    while (null != (line=sr.ReadLine()))
                    {
                        foreach (Match m in r.Matches(line))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

where xxx is the file name, obviously you will use the matching digit in a more elegant way than dumping on the console ;)