# Convert hexadecimal charArray to String

Tags: c++, c

I have a serious and irritating problem, please help

`mdContext->digest[i]` is an unsigned char Array with hexadecimal values so

```
for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    printf ("%02x", mdContext->digest[i]);
```

prints `900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72`

now.... I want to get this value in a char Array, i.e if I do

```
printf("%s",ArrayConverted);
```

I want to print the above string... Please help me in doing this

Things I tried

#### Trial-1

```
unsigned char in[64]=0;
  int tempValue[64];
 

  for (i = 0; i < 16; i++){
      sprintf(&tempValue[i],"%02x", (unsigned char)mdContext->digest[i]);
          in[i]=(unsigned char)tempValue[i];
  }
  
 printf("%s\n\n\n",in);
```

This prints
`90593d4bd9372e77`   But Original content is `900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72`

So it is skipping many characters in between... please help me converting this hexadecimal Char array in to a String

Comment: change tempValue to a `char` array, vice `int`, and see what you get.

Answer (score 5):

```
char tempValue[33]; // 32 hex digits + 0-terminator
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
  sprintf(tempValue + 2*i, "%02x", (unsigned char)mdContext->digest[i]);
```

Each byte requires two hexadecimal digits - so adjust the start position for `sprintf` with `2*i`

`tempValue + 2*i` is the same as `&tempValue[2*i]`

EDIT: A correct c++ version.

```
std::stringstream s;
for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) 
  s << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << (unsigned short) mdContext->digest[i];
std::cout << s.str() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

C++ specific solution:

```
    #include <sstream> 
    #include <iomanip>

    std::stringstream s;
    s.fill('0');
    for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < 16 ; ++i )
       s << std::setw(2) << std::hex <<(unsigned short)mdContext->digest[i]);
    std::cout << s.str() << endl;
```

Small demo : http://ideone.com/sTiEn

Comment: @Erik: Updated. See if it's fixed now.

Comment: @Nawaz: Don't you just hate streams :P - I'll remove comments now, please add the setfill as well

Comment: @Erik: Oops. Fixed that as well :D. BTW, why did you say "don't you just hate streams"? :-/

Comment: @Nawaz: Don't everyone hate streams? I mean, **look** at the syntax for simple printing of hex values... I'm usually very fond of C++ constructs, but the streams are, well, not the most clever part of the stdlib :P

Comment: @Erik: Yeah. Here it looks ugly. But sometimes it's really very smart. For example see the SECOND solution here in my post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888879/elegant-ways-to-count-the-frequency-of-words-in-a-file/4888916#4888916

Comment: @Nawaz: I usually use streams for debug logging, i like the type safety. But sometimes sprintf just beats everything else :)

Comment: @Erik: Do you think sprintf family can beat stream in the link I gave you?

Comment: @Nawaz: hehe no. Streams can be used for lots of clever things, but formatting isn't one of them :)

Comment: @Erik: Yeah. True. When it comes to formatting, printf-family beat streams. But once in while I try using stringstream so I don't forget how to use it; that means, this solution is not only for others, but for me as well :D