# tokenizing a string of data into a vector of structs?

Tags: c++, string, tokenize, winsock2

So I have the following string of data, which is being received through a TCP winsock connection, and would like to do an advanced tokenization, into a vector of structs, where each struct represents one record.

```
std::string buf = "44:william:adama:commander:stuff\n33:luara:roslin:president:data\n"

struct table_t
{
    std::string key;
    std::string first;
    std::string last;
    std::string rank;
    std::additional;
};
```

Each record in the string is delimited by a carriage return. My attempt at splitting up the records, but not yet splitting up the fields:

```
    void tokenize(std::string& str, std::vector< string >records)
{
    // Skip delimiters at beginning.
    std::string::size_type lastPos = str.find_first_not_of("\n", 0);
    // Find first "non-delimiter".
    std::string::size_type pos     = str.find_first_of("\n", lastPos);
    while (std::string::npos != pos || std::string::npos != lastPos)
    {
        // Found a token, add it to the vector.
        records.push_back(str.substr(lastPos, pos - lastPos));
        // Skip delimiters.  Note the "not_of"
        lastPos = str.find_first_not_of("\n", pos);
        // Find next "non-delimiter"
        pos = str.find_first_of("\n", lastPos);
    }
}
```

It seems totally unnecessary to repeat all of that code again to further tokenize each record via the colon (internal field separator) into the struct and push each struct into a vector. I'm sure there is a better way of doing this, or perhaps the design is in itself wrong.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: If you can use boost, this would be rather neatly done with its tokenizer library, its string algorithm library, or, for the most robust solution, with `boost.spirit`, as in here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/employee___parsing_into_structs.html

Comment: use [boost::tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/tokenizer/index.html)

Comment: missed this comment. +1 for spirit altho that is too heavy for the data format used in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For breaking the string up into records, I'd use istringstream, if only
because that will simplify the changes later when I want to read from
a file.  For tokenizing, the most obvious solution is boost::regex, so:

```
std::vector<table_t> parse( std::istream& input )
{
    std::vector<table_t> retval;
    std::string line;
    while ( std::getline( input, line ) ) {
        static boost::regex const pattern(
            "\([^:]*\):\([^:]*\):\([^:]*\):\([^:]*\):\([^:]*\)" );
        boost::smatch matched;
        if ( !regex_match( line, matched, pattern ) ) {
            //  Error handling...
        } else {
            retval.push_back(
                table_t( matched[1], matched[2], matched[3],
                         matched[4], matched[5] ) );
        }
    }
    return retval;
}
```

(I've assumed the logical constructor for table_t.  Also: there's a very
long tradition in C that names ending in _t are typedef's, so you're
probably better off finding some other convention.)

Comment: you should ping Siek and tell him ::tokenizer is useless since with regex you can do anything. obviously

Comment: @adirau He asked how to avoid duplication.  Using an existing tool is the obvious solution.  In this case, it's also clearly the simplest solution (at least if you want to check for errors).

Comment: avoid duplication by code reuse; can't say that if you use getline as the first tokenizer and regex as the second tokenizer you're avoiding duplication ;) not the simplest, not the obvious and not even if you want to check for errors; that regex will accept errors at token level; if he needs error checking maybe ::spirit is a better solution as Cubbi mentioned in the first comment

Comment: boost::spirit is overkill for something this simple.  (In fact, for just about everything I've seen where it isn't overkill, an external parser generator would be better.)  The regular expression solution is simple and easily understood.  (I considered other solutions, but just posted the simplest.)

Comment: ::spirit is in fact fast but you have a point it doesn't apply here

Comment: @adirau The resulting parser may be fast, but the compile times sure aren't:-).  Generating a parser is better handled by an external code generator than with template meta-programming.

Comment: I had no idea that what I was looking for would be so complicated! This works fine. I discovered I could also make things simpler by not separating each record with a line break, and just keep a note of how many fields should be expected, by reversing the struct and putting vectors inside it.

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
struct colon_separated_only: std::ctype<char> 
{
    colon_separated_only(): std::ctype<char>(get_table()) {}

    static std::ctype_base::mask const* get_table()
    {
        typedef std::ctype<char> cctype;
        static const cctype::mask *const_rc= cctype::classic_table();

        static cctype::mask rc[cctype::table_size];
        std::memcpy(rc, const_rc, cctype::table_size * sizeof(cctype::mask));

        rc[':'] = std::ctype_base::space; 
        return &rc[0];
    }
};

struct table_t
{
    std::string key;
    std::string first;
    std::string last;
    std::string rank;
    std::string additional;
};

int main() {
        std::string buf = "44:william:adama:commander:stuff\n33:luara:roslin:president:data\n";
        stringstream s(buf);
        s.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new colon_separated_only()));
        table_t t;
        std::vector<table_t> data;
        while ( s >> t.key >> t.first >> t.last >> t.rank >> t.additional )
        {
           data.push_back(t);
        }
        for(size_t i = 0 ; i < data.size() ; ++i )
        {
           cout << data[i].key <<" ";
           cout << data[i].first <<" "<<data[i].last <<" ";
           cout << data[i].rank <<" "<< data[i].additional << endl;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
44 william adama commander stuff
33 luara roslin president data
```

Online Demo : http://ideone.com/JwZuk

---

The technique I used here is described in my another solution to different question:

[Elegant ways to count the frequency of words in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888879/elegant-ways-to-count-the-frequency-of-words-in-a-file/4888916#4888916)

Comment: I have yet to check out ctype, will have to read up on it. Thank you for your help.