# C++, how to tokenize this string?

Tags: c++, scanf

How can I get string like "Ac milan" and "Real Madryt" if they are separated with whitespace?

Here is my attempt:

```
string linia = "Ac milan ; Real Madryt ; 0 ; 2";
str = new char [linia.size()+1];
strcpy(str, linia.c_str());
sscanf(str, "%s ; %s ; %d ; %d", a, b, &c, &d);
```

but it doesn't work; I have: `a= Ac;` `b = (null); c=0; d=2;`

Comment: See my solution here : [tokenizing a string of data into a vector of structs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462022/tokenizing-a-string-of-data-into-a-vector-of-structs/5462907#5462907)

Comment: Personally, I'm partial to my own solution. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046747/c-stl-selective-iterator/3047106#3047106

Comment: BTW, it is Real Madrid, not Real Madryt :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, sscanf *can* do what you're asking for, using a scanset conversion:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){ 

    char a[20], b[20];
    int c=0, d=0;
    std::string linia("Ac milan ; Real Madryt ; 0 ; 2");
    sscanf(linia.c_str(), " %19[^;]; %19[^;] ;%d ;%d", a, b, &c, &d);

    std::cout << a << "\n" << b << "\n" << c << "\n" << d << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The output produced by this is:

```
Ac milan
Real Madryt
0
2
```

Comment: Don't like scanf, but a plus for using the length specifiers, to avoid buffer overrun.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to go the C++ way, you can use `getline`, using `;` as the delimiter, as follows.

```
string s = "Ac milan ; Real Madryt ; 0 ; 2";
string s0, s1;
istringstream iss(s);
getline(iss, s0, ';');
getline(iss, s1, ';');
```

Comment: @Jerry: Thanks. I' didn't know about scanset conversions. I changed my answer accordingly. +1 for you.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have `;` as a separator character in the string so you can split the string based on that character. [`boost::split`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id1701774) is useful for this:

```
string linia = "Ac milan ; Real Madryt ; 0 ; 2";
list<string> splitresults;

boost::split(splitresults, linia, boost::is_any_of(";"));
```

See [Split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string) for other techniques for splitting strings.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use the `std::string::find_first_of()` method that allows you to search for character (delimiters) starting from a given position, e.g.

```
size_t tok_end = linia.find_first_of(";", prev_tok_end+1);
token = linia.substr(prev_tok_end+1, prev_tok_end+1 - tok_end);
```

However, the `boost` solution is the most elegant.