# how to tokenize a string

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I tokenize a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)

hello every one i want to divide my string into two parts based on '\t' is there any built in function i tried strtok but it take char * as first in put but my variable is of type string
thanks

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502368/c-how-to-tokenize-this-string and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {
   std::string str("abc\tdef");
   char split_char = '\t';
   std::istringstream split(str);
   std::vector<std::string> token;

   for(std::string each; std::getline(split, each, split_char); token.push_back(each));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use C standard library?

Variant 1.
Use std::string::c_str() function to convert a std::string to a C-string (char *)

Variant 2.
Use std::string::find(char, size_t) to find a necessary symbol ('\t' in your case) than make a new string with std::string::substr. Loop saving a 'current position' till the end of line.

Comment: Your "Variant 2" solution uses the C++ Standard Library, not the C standard library. Your "Variant 1" solution is incomplete.