# Right way to split an std::string into a vector<string>

Tags: c++, string

What is the right way to split a string into a vector of strings? Delimiter is space or comma.

Comment: A split in which commas and spaces are both delimiters, or a function that splits either on space or on comma, according to a parameter?

Comment: Some of the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string can readily be adapted to work with multiple delimiters.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

For space separated strings, then you can do this:

```
std::string s = "What is the right way to split a string into a vector of strings";
std::stringstream ss(s);
std::istream_iterator<std::string> begin(ss);
std::istream_iterator<std::string> end;
std::vector<std::string> vstrings(begin, end);
std::copy(vstrings.begin(), vstrings.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Output:

```
What
is
the
right
way
to
split
a
string
into
a
vector
of
strings
```

---

## string that have both comma and space

```
struct tokens: std::ctype<char> 
{
    tokens(): std::ctype<char>(get_table()) {}
 
    static std::ctype_base::mask const* get_table()
    {
        typedef std::ctype<char> cctype;
        static const cctype::mask *const_rc= cctype::classic_table();
 
        static cctype::mask rc[cctype::table_size];
        std::memcpy(rc, const_rc, cctype::table_size * sizeof(cctype::mask));
 
        rc[','] = std::ctype_base::space; 
        rc[' '] = std::ctype_base::space; 
        return &rc[0];
    }
};
 
std::string s = "right way, wrong way, correct way";
std::stringstream ss(s);
ss.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new tokens()));
std::istream_iterator<std::string> begin(ss);
std::istream_iterator<std::string> end;
std::vector<std::string> vstrings(begin, end);
std::copy(vstrings.begin(), vstrings.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Output:

```
right
way
wrong
way
correct
way
```

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> vstrings(begin, end);` would be nicer IMO, but I suppose we don't know whether the questioner is constructing the vector, or hoping to populate a pre-existing vector.

Comment: Nice, but wrong. The OP was specific in that both space and comma are delimeters. And you can't do the same trick in this case, can you?

Comment: @Steve: Nice suggestion. @Armen: OP didn't mention anything when I gave the solution. The question doesn't seem to be clear enough. Otherwise there're some elegant ways to deal with both space and comma simultenously: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888879/elegant-ways-to-count-the-frequency-of-words-in-a-file

Comment: I like the use of `istream_iterator` but why not finish strong using `ostream_iterator` as well?

Comment: @Oli, @Steve and @Armen: Please see my second solution. And let me know if it can still be improved. :-)

Comment: @Nawaz: the obvious possible improvement would be to replace the final `for` loop with a call to `std::copy`.

Comment: @Jerry: haha.. nice one. forgot that though other times I make use of it as well. thanks for reminding it. :-)

Comment: This is an amazing answer and needs to be highlighted somehow.

Comment: @Samveen: Thanks for the appreciation. :-)

Comment: +1 Very nice. But don't you have to delete the tokens struct created in `ss.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new tokens()))` somewhere?

Comment: @Yes, I thought the read will do that. Use`auto loc  = std::make_shared<tokens>()`, and then pass `ss.imbue(...,  loc.get()));`. That should work.

Comment: @StringerBell The token-facet should be cleaned up by locale's destructor.

Answer (score 144):

A convenient way would be [boost's string algorithms library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id2728530).

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp> // Include boost::for is_any_of
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp> // Include for boost::split
// ...

std::vector<std::string> words;
std::string s;
boost::split(words, s, boost::is_any_of(", "), boost::token_compress_on);
```

Comment: What is `token_compress_on` for?

Comment: @pooya13 From the documentation: If `eCompress` (the fourth argument) is set to `token_compress_on`, adjacent separators are merged together. Otherwise, every two separators delimit a token. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/split_id820181.html

Answer (score 40):

You can use getline with delimiter:

```
string s, tmp; 
stringstream ss(s);
vector<string> words;

while(getline(ss, tmp, ',')){
    words.push_back(tmp);
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 21):

```
vector<string> split(string str, string token){
    vector<string>result;
    while(str.size()){
        int index = str.find(token);
        if(index!=string::npos){
            result.push_back(str.substr(0,index));
            str = str.substr(index+token.size());
            if(str.size()==0)result.push_back(str);
        }else{
            result.push_back(str);
            str = "";
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

> split("1,2,3",",")  ==> ["1","2","3"]
>
> split("1,2,",",")  ==> ["1","2",""]
>
> split("1token2token3","token") ==> ["1","2","3"]

Comment: I think we can use `break;` instead of `str = "";` as it unnecessarily adds empty string in the result if token is not found. split("1234", ",") ==> ["1234", ""]

Answer (score 10):

If the string has both spaces and commas you can use the string class function

```
found_index = myString.find_first_of(delims_str, begin_index)
```

in a loop. Checking for != npos and inserting into a vector. If you prefer old school you can also use C's

```
strtok()
```

method.

Answer (score 8):

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> split(std::string text, char delim) {
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    std::stringstream ss(text);
    while(std::getline(ss, line, delim)) {
        vec.push_back(line);
    }
    return vec;
}
```

`split("String will be split", ' ')` -> `{"String", "will", "be", "split"}`

`split("Hello, how are you?", ',')` -> `{"Hello", "how are you?"}`

**EDIT:** Here's a thing I made, this can use multi-char delimiters, albeit I'm not 100% sure if it always works:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> split(std::string text, std::string delim) {
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    size_t pos = 0, prevPos = 0;
    while (1) {
        pos = text.find(delim, prevPos);
        if (pos == std::string::npos) {
            vec.push_back(text.substr(prevPos));
            return vec;
        }

        vec.push_back(text.substr(prevPos, pos - prevPos));
        prevPos = pos + delim.length();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Tweaked version from [Techie Delight](https://www.techiedelight.com/split-string-cpp-using-delimiter/):

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& str, char delim) {
    std::vector<std::string> strings;
    size_t start;
    size_t end = 0;
    while ((start = str.find_first_not_of(delim, end)) != std::string::npos) {
        end = str.find(delim, start);
        strings.push_back(str.substr(start, end - start));
    }
    return strings;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my variant that work somelike as explode function in PHP, we provide given string and delimiters list.

```
std::vector< std::string > explode(const std::string& data, const std::string& delimiters) {
    auto is_delim = [&](auto & c) { return delimiters.find(c) != std::string::npos; };
    std::vector< std::string > result;
    for (std::string::size_type i(0), len(data.length()), pos(0); i <= len; i++) {
        if (is_delim(data[i]) || i == len) {
            auto tok = data.substr(pos, i - pos);
            if ( !tok.empty() )
                result.push_back( tok );
            pos = i + 1;
        }
    } return result;
}
```

example of usage

```
std::string test_delimiters("hello, there is lots of, delimiters, that may be even together,  ");

auto dem_res = explode(test_delimiters, " ,"); // space or comma

for (auto word : dem_res) {
    std::cout << word << '\n';
} std::cout << "end\n";
```

the ouput:

```
hello
there
is
lots
of
delimiters
that
may
be
even
together
end
```

Answer (score 0):

i made this custom function that will convert the line to vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string line;
    getline(cin, line);
    int len = line.length();
    vector<string> subArray;

    for (int j = 0, k = 0; j < len; j++) {
        if (line[j] == ' ') {
            string ch = line.substr(k, j - k);
            k = j+1;
            subArray.push_back(ch);
        }
        if (j == len - 1) {
            string ch = line.substr(k, j - k+1);
            subArray.push_back(ch);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version of roach's solution that splits based on a string of single character delimiters + supports the option to compress duplicate delimiters.

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> split(std::string text, std::string delim, bool compress) 
{
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    size_t pos = 0, prevPos = 0;
    while (1) 
    {
        pos = text.find_first_of(delim, prevPos);

        while(compress) 
        {
            if( prevPos == pos )
                prevPos++;
            else
                break;

            pos = text.find_first_of(delim, prevPos);
        }

        if (pos == std::string::npos) {
            if(prevPos != text.size())
                vec.push_back(text.substr(prevPos));
            return vec;
        }

        vec.push_back(text.substr(prevPos, pos - prevPos));
        prevPos = pos + 1;
    }
}
```

Example without compress:

```cpp
std::string s = "  1.2  foo@foo . ";
auto res = split(s, ".@ ", false);
    for(auto i : res)
        std::cout << "string {" << i << "}" << std::endl;
```

Output:

```cpp
string {}
string {}
string {1}
string {2}
string {}
string {foo}
string {foo}
string {}
string {}
```

With compress `split(s, ".@ ", true);`

```cpp
string {1}
string {2}
string {foo}
string {foo}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that will split up a `string` into a `vector` but it doesn't include empty strings in the output `vector`.

```
vector<string> split(string str, string token) {
    vector<string> result;
    while (str.size()) {
        int index = str.find(token);
        string substr;
        if ((substr = str.substr(0, index)) == "") {
            str = str.substr(index + token.size());
        } else if (index != string::npos) {
            result.push_back(substr);
            str = str.substr(index + token.size());
        } else {
            result.push_back(str);
            str = "";
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note: The above was adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46943631/14062356) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Usage

```
void test() {
    string a = "hello : world : ok : fine";
    auto r = split(a, " : ", 2);
    for (auto e: r) {
        cout << e << endl;
    }
}


static inline std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &str, const std::string &delimiter = " ", const int max_elements = 0) {
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    std::string::size_type start_index = 0;
    while (true) {
        std::string::size_type next_index = str.find(delimiter, start_index);
        if (next_index == std::string::npos) {
            tokens.push_back(str.substr(start_index));
            break;
        } else {
            tokens.push_back(str.substr(start_index, next_index - start_index));
            start_index = next_index + delimiter.length();
        }
        if (max_elements > 0 && tokens.size() == max_elements - 1) {
            tokens.push_back(str.substr(start_index));
            break;
        }
    }

    return tokens;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.