# C++ Parsing input string to variables

Tags: c++, string, parsing

All i need to do is to parse the input string of your full name, into 3 separate names so I can take the first initials of each and print them. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;    
int main()
{
    string [parsed_output] = fullName.split(" ");
    string firstName = parsed_output[0];
    string middleName = parsed_ouput[1];
    string lastName = parsed_output[2];
    string fullName;
    char firstLetter = firstName[0];
    char middleLetter = middleName[0];
    char lastLetter = lastName[0];
    cout << "Enter your first name, middle name or initial, and last name separated by                              spaces: \n"; 
    cin >> fullName;

    cout << "Your initials are: " << firstLetter << middleLetter << lastLetter << '\n';
    cout << "Your name is: " << firstName << " " << middleName << " " << lastName << '\n';
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607589/right-way-to-split-an-stdstring-into-a-vectorstring - After splitting the name, go ahead and iterate over the sub-strings and for each one print the first character, i.e. if `length() > 0` print `subString[0]`. As shown in the answers below, you can also just take the names separately. Unless processing the complete name at once is an absolute requirement.

Comment: `fullName` is not declared, and you want to parse it before putting anything into it? I think you need some basics first.

Answer (score 3):

You're making things way to complicated. What's the meaning of 'parsed_output[0];' and 'fullName' anyway? You could just do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;    

int main()
{
  string firstName, middleName, lastName;
  cout << "Enter your first name, middle name or initial, and last name separated by                              spaces: \n"; 
  cin >> firstName >> middleName >> lastName;
  char firstLetter = firstName[0];
  char middleLetter = middleName[0];
  char lastLetter = lastName[0];
  cout << "Your initials are: " << firstLetter << middleLetter << lastLetter << '\n';
  cout << "Your name is: " << firstName << " " << middleName << " " << lastName << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

The whole Point of [`std::cin`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cin/) is, that you get an stream to space separated tokens with the extraction operator '>>'. If you want to extract the first, middle & last names by Hand (like in hasans answer), then you would need the whole string in the first place (a string with all 3 names and whitespaces as limiter). To read in input with containing spaces you would use [`std::getline(std::cin, fullName)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) instead of `std::cin`, because `std::cin` will extract the Input until the first trailing whitespace is encountered.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use e.g. [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to get the full name, and [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) for the parsing:

```
std::string fullName;
std::getline(std::cin, fullName);

std::istringstream iss(fullName);

std::string firstName, middleName, lastName;
iss >> firstName >> middleName >> lastName;
```

Comment: Won't `std::cin >> fullName` stop at whitespace? You would need to use `std::getline` to require parsing.