# Parsing a string down into an array of c_strings

Tags: c++, arrays, parsing

I wrote some code in order to turn a string (read in with getline()) into an array of c_strings. The problem I'm having is that the items I'm reading is not being stored in the array properly. I originally parsed the input based on the number of spaces in between them, and then going on from there, but that also got me the same problem. So I changed my parsing into what's below me, and I'm getting the same exact problem, suggesting to me that my parsing works, but somewhere in the process of reading what's parsed into the char* array, something is going wrong.

My code:

```
int i = 0;
unsigned inputSize = input.size();
unsigned int prev = 0; //prev as in previous space position
while((prev = input.find(' ', prev)) < inputSize) {
    ++i;    ++prev;        
}
char* charArray[i + 2];
memset(charArray, '\0', i + 2);  
stringstream ss(input);
string buffer;
for(int a = 0; ss >> buffer; ++a) {
    charArray[a] = const_cast<char*>(buffer.c_str());
}
```

What I'm doing is that I'm counting the number of spaces of my input, and making a char* array of that number + 2 (+2 because I need to end it with NULL). After that, I parse my input and read it into the array. I am using ss >> buffer as my termination clause because I will not end up allocating memory outside the allocated memory for charArray. buffer.c_str gets me a const char*, so I const_cast it in order for me to store it into the (non-const) array of char*. I use memset to set all elements to NULL because I know it'll be written over, except the last element, which I want to remain NULL.

Test:

```
Input: Why hello world
Output: Junk
```

What's going wrong inside my program?

Comment: How about some comments to tell use what you think the code is doing?

Comment: Just put that in, but I'll put more info on what I think the parsing is doing.

Comment: Is there a really good reason you can't put the input into a stringstream, then read words from there to, say, a `std::vector<string>`?

Comment: I'm putting my input into execv().

Answer (score 0):

The pointer returned by `buffer.c_str()` is valid only as long as the string stored in `buffer` is not modified. If you need to modify `buffer`, you have to copy its contents beforehand, if you need the old content later on.

Answer (score 0):

See [Right way to split an std::string into a vector [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607589/right-way-to-split-an-stdstring-into-a-vectorstring).

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/761aeb3b5e207296)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::string input = "Why hello world";
    std::stringstream ss(input);

    std::vector<std::string> vstrings(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(ss),
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>{}); // C++11 brace syntax
    char** charArray = new char*[vstrings.size()];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vstrings.size(); i++)
        charArray[i] = (char*)vstrings[i].c_str();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vstrings.size(); i++)
        std::cout << charArray[i] << "\n";
    delete[] charArray;
}
```