# How to split string read from text file into array using c++

Tags: c++, split

I want to split the strings on each line of my text file into an array, similar to the split() function in python. my desired syntax is a loop that enters every split-string into the next index of an array, 
so for example if my string:
"ab,cd,ef,gh,ij"

, every time I encounter a comma then I would:
datafile >> arr1[i]

and my array would end up:
arr1 = [ab,cd,ef,gh,ij]

a mock code without reading a text file is provided below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char str[] = "ab,cd,ef,gh,ij";  //" ex str in place of file contents/fstream sFile;"
    const int NUM = 5;
    string sArr[NUM];//empty array
    char *token = strtok(str, ",");
    for (int i=0; i < NUM; i++)
        while((token!=NULL)){
            ("%s\n", token) >> sArr[i];
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
         }
    cout >> sArr;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get a invalid operand to binary error as well I think it's because im using string.h and string in my directives

Comment: You will get useful information and better methods here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607589/right-way-to-split-an-stdstring-into-a-vectorstring

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Right way to split an std::string into a vector<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607589/right-way-to-split-an-stdstring-into-a-vectorstring)

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you can read a file line by line and directly get a `std::string`.

You will found below an example I made with a `split()` proposal as you requested, and a `main()` example of reading a file:

**Example**

*data file:*

```
ab,cd,ef,gh
ij,kl,mn
```

*c++ code:*

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string & s, char c);

int main()
{
    std::string file_path("data.txt"); // I assumed you have that kind of file
    std::ifstream in_s(file_path);

    std::vector <std::vector<std::string>> content;

    if(in_s)
    {
        std::string line;
        std::vector <std::string> vec;
        while(getline(in_s, line))
        {
            for(const std::string & str : split(line, ','))
                vec.push_back(str);
            content.push_back(vec);
            vec.clear();
        }

        in_s.close();
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Could not open: " + file_path << std::endl;

    for(const std::vector<std::string> & str_vec : content)
    {
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < str_vec.size(); ++i)
            std::cout << str_vec[i] << ((i == str_vec.size()-1) ? ("") : (" : "));
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string & s, char c)
{
    std::vector<std::string> splitted;

    std::string word;
    for(char ch : s)
    {
        if((ch == c) && (!word.empty()))
        {
            splitted.push_back(word);
            word.clear();
        }
        else
            word += ch;
    }
    if(!word.empty())
        splitted.push_back(word);

    return splitted;
}
```

*output:*

> ab : cd : ef : gh
>   ij : kl : mn

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

So, a few things to fix.  Firstly, arrays and `NUM` are kind of limiting - you have to fix up NUM whenever you change the input string, so C++ provides `std::vector` which can resize itself to however many strings it finds.  Secondly, you want to call `strtok` until it returns `nullptr` once, and you can do that with one loop.  With both your `for` and `NUM` you call `strtok` too many times - even after it has returned `nullptr`.  Next, to put the `token` into a `std::string`, you would assign using `my_string = token;` rather than `("%s\n", token) >> my_string` - which is a broken mix of `printf()` formatting and C++ streaming notation.  Lastly, to print the elements you've extracted, you can use another loop.  All these changes are illustrated below.

```
char str[] = "ab,cd,ef,gh,ij";
std::vector<std::string> strings;
char* token = strtok(str, ",");
while ((token != nullptr))
{
    strings.push_back(token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
}
for (const auto& s : strings)
    cout >> s >> '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is overly complicated and wrong.

You probably want this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
int main() {
  char str[] = "ab,cd,ef,gh,ij";  //" ex str in place of file contents/fstream sFile;"
  const int NUM = 5;
  string sArr[NUM];//empty array
  char *token = strtok(str, ",");

  int max = 0;
  while ((token != NULL)) {
    sArr[max++] = token;
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    cout << sArr[i] << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

This code is still poor and no bound checking is done.

But anyway, you should rather do it the C++ way as suggested in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use `boost::split`

```
    #include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
    [...]          
    std::vector<std::string> strings;
    std::string val("ab,cd,ef,gh,ij");
    boost::split(strings, val, boost::is_any_of(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
std::string str = "ab,cd,ef,gh,ij";
std::vector<std::string> TokenList;

std::string::size_type lastPos = 0;
std::string::size_type pos  = str.find_first_of(',', lastPos);

while(pos != std::string::npos)
{
    std::string temp(str, lastPos, pos - lastPos);
    TokenList.push_back(temp);
    lastPos = pos + 1;
    pos  = str.find_first_of(',', lastPos);
}

if(lastPos != str.size())
{
    std::string temp(str, lastPos, str.size());
    TokenList.push_back(temp);
}

for(int i = 0; i < TokenList.size(); i++)
    std::cout << TokenList.at(i) << std::endl;
```