# Split a string into words by multiple delimiters

Tags: c++, string, token, delimiter

I have some text (meaningful text or arithmetical expression) and I want to split it into words.
If I had a single delimiter, I'd use:

```
std::stringstream stringStream(inputString);
std::string word;
while(std::getline(stringStream, word, delimiter)) 
{
    wordVector.push_back(word);
}
```

How can I break the string into tokens with several delimiters?

Comment: Boost.StringAlgorithm or Boost.Tokenizer would help.

Comment: Or, some idea you can get from this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888879/elegant-ways-to-count-the-frequency-of-words-in-a-file

Comment: @K-ballo: According to the question, you should not use external libraries like Boost.

Comment: @MasoudM.: Does Boost still count as an external library ;) ? As far as I am concerned, Boost is like my Standard Library, it's built-in!

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Then, Qt is not external library for me too.

Comment: Thanks for the link on frequency counting! :)

Comment: @MasoudM.: To each its own :) The one key difference though is that a number of Boost libraries are experimentation before inclusion in the Standard (Boost.Regex, Boost.Thread and Boost.Unordered have been included with few tweaks in C++11, Boost.FS is the basis for the filesystem reflexion for C++1x).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Assuming one of the delimiters is newline, the following reads the line and further splits it by the delimiters.  For this example I've chosen the delimiters space, apostrophe, and semi-colon.

```
std::stringstream stringStream(inputString);
std::string line;
while(std::getline(stringStream, line)) 
{
    std::size_t prev = 0, pos;
    while ((pos = line.find_first_of(" ';", prev)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        if (pos > prev)
            wordVector.push_back(line.substr(prev, pos-prev));
        prev = pos+1;
    }
    if (prev < line.length())
        wordVector.push_back(line.substr(prev, std::string::npos));
}
```

Comment: You're too fast for me :p If newline is not a delimiter, then simply picking one of the "regular" delimiters (and removing it from the inner loop) will work.

Comment: This is the most reasonable way to split by multiple delimiters on the internet without using boost/crazy templates

Answer (score 24):

If you have boost, you could use:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
std::string inputString("One!Two,Three:Four");
std::string delimiters("|,:");
std::vector<std::string> parts;
boost::split(parts, inputString, boost::is_any_of(delimiters));
```

Comment: that's like asking someone to open a jar of pickles, and you pull out a chainsaw.

Answer (score 22):

### Using `std::regex`

A `std::regex` can do string splitting in a few lines:

```
std::regex re("[\\|,:]");
std::sregex_token_iterator first{input.begin(), input.end(), re, -1}, last;//the '-1' is what makes the regex split (-1 := what was not matched)
std::vector<std::string> tokens{first, last};
```

[Try it yourself](https://godbolt.org/z/rQZkNj)

Comment: How come this has only few up votes. This is absolutely brilliant ! Few lines, no need for external library and something novel. Thank you very much !

Comment: @berkayberabi no problem - it was a late answer, I think thats why. If you want to, you can post a bounty to reward an existing answer (that also draws attention).

Comment: Hi I dont have that much reputation. But one more question I have. If I also want to split based on brackets as delimeter([]) how can I pass the brackets. If I just enter them, they will be interpreted as another regular expression and it does not work

Comment: @berkayberabi escape via `\\]`

Comment: How about this case? text = "Windows. Apple";

I only want to see ['Windows' , 'Apple']. This regex gives [`Windows` ,'  ', `Apple`], which contains a  space (' ') I dont want.

Comment: @cpchung it all depends on your input and what your aim is. In your case, just make match multiple with sometime like [\\.\\s]+ should solve it.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know why nobody pointed out the manual way, but here it is:

```
const std::string delims(";,:. \n\t");
inline bool isDelim(char c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < delims.size(); ++i)
        if (delims[i] == c)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

and in function:

```
std::stringstream stringStream(inputString);
std::string word; char c;

while (stringStream) {
    word.clear();

    // Read word
    while (!isDelim((c = stringStream.get()))) 
        word.push_back(c);
    if (c != EOF)
        stringStream.unget();

    wordVector.push_back(word);

    // Read delims
    while (isDelim((c = stringStream.get())));
    if (c != EOF)
        stringStream.unget();
}
```

This way you can do something useful with the delims if you want.

Comment: You can move std::string word; and char c; inside the loop and avoid using clear()... variables should be as local and short-lived as possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you interesting in how to do it yourself and not using boost.

Assuming the delimiter string may be very long - let say M, checking for every char in your string if it is a delimiter, would cost O(M) each, so doing so in a loop for all chars in your original string, let say in length N,  is O(M*N).

I would use a dictionary (like a map - "delimiter" to "booleans" - but here I would use a simple boolean array that has true in index = ascii value for each delimiter).

Now iterating on the string and check if the char is a delimiter is O(1), which eventually gives us O(N) overall.

Here is my sample code:

```
const int dictSize = 256;    

vector<string> tokenizeMyString(const string &s, const string &del)
{
    static bool dict[dictSize] = { false};

    vector<string> res;
    for (int i = 0; i < del.size(); ++i) {      
        dict[del[i]] = true;
    }

    string token("");
    for (auto &i : s) {
        if (dict[i]) {
            if (!token.empty()) {
                res.push_back(token);
                token.clear();
            }           
        }
        else {
            token += i;
        }
    }
    if (!token.empty()) {
        res.push_back(token);
    }
    return res;
}


int main()
{
    string delString = "MyDog:Odie, MyCat:Garfield  MyNumber:1001001";
//the delimiters are " " (space) and "," (comma) 
    vector<string> res = tokenizeMyString(delString, " ,");

    for (auto &i : res) {

        cout << "token: " << i << endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Note: tokenizeMyString returns vector by value and create it on the stack first, so we're using here the power of the compiler >>> RVO - return value optimization :)

Answer (score 1):

And here, ages later, a solution using C++20:

```
constexpr std::string_view words{"Hello-_-C++-_-20-_-!"};
constexpr std::string_view delimeters{"-_-"};
for (const std::string_view word : std::views::split(words, delimeters)) {
    std::cout << std::quoted(word) << ' ';
}
// outputs: Hello C++ 20!
```

Required headers:

```
#include <ranges>
#include <string_view>
```

Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/split_view

Comment: Thanks! Anyone who wants to use this please check the reference link. The example is a bit different in the current docs.

Comment: This is incorrect. The OP was asking about using multiple delimiters. This answer uses the single, multi-character delimiter `-_-`. If you have the input `"Hello,C++;20,"` and use `std::views::split(words ",;"_sv)`, it won't split anything, because `,;` does not appear in the input.

Answer (score 0):

Using Eric Niebler's range-v3 library:

https://godbolt.org/z/ZnxfSa

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "range/v3/all.hpp"

int main()
{
    std::string s = "user1:192.168.0.1|user2:192.168.0.2|user3:192.168.0.3";
    auto words = s  
        | ranges::view::split('|')
        | ranges::view::transform([](auto w){
            return w | ranges::view::split(':');
        });
      ranges::for_each(words, [](auto i){ std::cout << i  << "\n"; });
}
```

Comment: How does this work for multiple delimiters?

Comment: You mean something like https://godbolt.org/z/1sYzhe7zq ?