# Split a string on multiple multi-char delimeters in C++

Tags: c++, string

How can I split a string on **multiple multi-character** delimiters?

I want a function like `vector<string> split_string(string input, vector<string> delims)`

For example, `split_string("foo+bar  := baz",{"+"," ",":="}) = {"foo","+","bar"," "," ",":="," ","baz"}`

Comment: A very good answer here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621727/split-a-string-into-words-by-multiple-delimiters-in-c

And more..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265581/parse-split-a-string-in-c-using-string-delimiter-standard-c

Comment: @jafar please link to a specific answer that works for multiple multi-char delimiters.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter please link to a specific answer that works for this question

Comment: The answer in the first link solves that problem.

Comment: The first link uses single character delimiters while the second link uses string delimiters precisely `=>`. Combining the two solves the issue.

Comment: That question has **57** answers, I'm pretty sure you can find one there that suits you.

Comment: @fread2281 my solution. http://pastebin.com/zxK2t55b

Comment: Say you have two delimiters, ":" and ":=". Which one wins?

Comment: Based on the comments you wrote so far, it appears that you might be under the impression that stackoverflow.com is a web site where someone writes your code for you, without you bothering to invest any effort in it yourself. You are mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

My cut at the same. I chose to go with divide and conquer. It is not fast. It is not efficient. But it is simple.

Unfortunately it didn't work in this case because we are preserving the delimiters in the output. Dividing allowed later delimiters to split previously found delimiters.

Eg:

```
Source :=foo+bar  .   :=baz+quaax:=  C++
Delims [+][ ][:=][:]
Result [:][=][foo][+][bar][ ][ ][.][ ][ ][ ][:][=][baz][+][quaax][:][=][ ][ ][C][+][+]
```

Yuck.

Finally settled on a similar approach to jafar's and added it to my support library to try out in a job I'm working on to replace the divide and conquer approach because it does look to be faster. Wouldn't have bothered posting this, but Jafar's is a bit over complicated for my tastes. Haven't done any profiling so his may be faster.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// easy vector output
template<class TYPE>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out,
                          const std::vector<TYPE> & in)
{
    for (const TYPE &val: in)
    {
        out << "["<< val << "]";
    }
    return out;
}

// find the first of many string delimiters
size_t multifind(size_t start,
                 const std::string & source,
                 const std::vector<std::string> &delims,
                 size_t & delfound)
{
    size_t lowest = std::string::npos;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < delims.size(); i++)
    {
        size_t pos = source.find(delims[i], start);
        if (pos == start)
        {
            lowest = pos;
            delfound = i;
            break;
        }
        else if (pos < lowest)
        {
            lowest = pos;
            delfound = i;
        }
    }
    return lowest;
}

// do the grunt work
std::vector<std::string> splitString(const std::string &source,
                                     const std::vector<std::string> &delims)
{
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;

    size_t current = 0;
    size_t delfound;
    size_t next = multifind(current,
                            source,
                            delims,
                            delfound);
    while(next != std::string::npos)
    {
        if (current < next)
        {
            tokens.push_back(source.substr(current, next - current));
        }
        tokens.push_back(delims[delfound]);
        current = next + delims[delfound].length();
        next = multifind(current,
                         source,
                         delims,
                         delfound);
    }
    if (current < source.length())
    {
        tokens.push_back(source.substr(current, std::string::npos));
    }
    return tokens;
}


void test(const std::string &source,
          const std::vector<std::string> &delims)
{
    std::cout << "Source " << source << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Delims " << delims << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Result " << splitString(source, delims) << std::endl << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    test(":=foo+bar  .   :=baz+quaax:=  C++", { " ",":=","+" });
    test(":=foo+bar  .   :=baz+quaax:=  C++", { ":=","+"," " });
    test(":=foo+bar  .   :=baz+quaax:=  C++", { "+"," ",":=" });
    test(":=foo+bar  .   :=baz+quaax:=  C++", { "+"," ",":=",":" });
    test(":=foo+bar  .   :=baz+quaax:=  C++", { ":"," ",":=","+" });
    test("foo+bar  .   :=baz+quaax:=  C++lalala", { "+"," ",":=",":" });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

std::vector<std::string> splitString(std::string input, std::vector<std::string> delimeters);
std::string findFirstOf(std::string input, std::vector<std::string> del);

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> words = splitString(":=foo+bar :=baz+quaax", { " ",":=","+" });
    for (std::string str : words)
        std::cout << str << ",";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    system("pause");
}
std::vector<std::string> splitString(std::string input, std::vector<std::string> delimeters)
{
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    size_t pos = 0;
    std::string token;
    std::string delimeter = findFirstOf(input, delimeters);

    while(delimeter != "")
    {
        if ((pos = input.find(delimeter)) != std::string::npos)
        {
            token = input.substr(0, pos);
            result.push_back(token);
            result.push_back(delimeter);
            input.erase(0, pos + delimeter.length());
        }
        delimeter = findFirstOf(input, delimeters);
    }
    result.push_back(input);
    return result;
}
//find the first delimeter in the string
std::string findFirstOf(std::string input, std::vector<std::string> del)
{

    //get a map of delimeter and position of delimeter
    size_t pos;
    std::map<std::string, size_t> m;

    for (int i = 0; i < del.size(); i++)
    {
        pos = input.find(del[i]);
        if (pos != std::string::npos)
            m[del[i]] = pos;
    }

    //find the smallest position of all delimeters i.e, find the smallest value in the map

    if (m.size() == 0)
        return "";

    size_t v = m.begin()->second;
    std::string k = m.begin()->first;

    for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); it++)
    {
        if (it->second < v)
        {
            v = it->second;
            k = it->first;
        }
    }
    return k;
}
```

output: `,:=,foo,+,bar, ,,:=,baz,+,quaax,`.

Comment: This expects the delimiters to be in the same order in the string as in the delimiter array

Comment: No. Change the order in the delimiter vector and see if the output is different. This issue is taken care of by `findFirstOf`

Comment: Okay, but `splitString(":=foo+bar  :=baz+quaax", { "+"," ",":=" }) = :=foo,+,bar  :=baz,+,quaax,`

Comment: Gotta say, that's more elegant than the N^2 divide and conquer monstrosity I had in mind.