# Split string into key-value pairs using C++

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a string like this:

```
"CA: ABCD\nCB: ABFG\nCC: AFBV\nCD: 4567"
```

Now `": "` splits key from value while `\n` separates the pairs. I want to add the key-value pairs to a map in C++.

Is there any efficient way of doing this considering optimization in mind?

Comment: Have you read the manual page for `std::string`

Comment: Using e.g. [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) could be a good start. Note that `std::getline` can be used for arbitrary separators, not only newlines.

Comment: Also don't worry about optimizations at this stage. First make sure your program works, then *benchmark*, *measure* and *profile* to find the bottlenecks, and optimize those. Premature optimization is only going to lead you astray.

Comment: you can implement it "as hoc", after that you can profile your solution and find slow places which you can optimize if you need.

Comment: Here on SO there's a strong correlation between the inability to do the task and asking for (the most) *efficient* way of doing it.

Comment: I think you can find some tips here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621727/split-a-string-into-words-by-multiple-delimiters-in-c

Comment: You can find some information from stackoverflow [C++ documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/488/stdstring/2148/tokenize)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well I have two methods here. The first one is the easy, obvious method that I use all the time (performance is rarely an issue). The second method is likely more efficient <s>but I have not done any formal timings</s>.

In my tests the second method is about 3 times faster.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

std::map<std::string, std::string> mappify1(std::string const& s)
{
    std::map<std::string, std::string> m;

    std::string key, val;
    std::istringstream iss(s);

    while(std::getline(std::getline(iss, key, ':') >> std::ws, val))
        m[key] = val;

    return m;
}

std::map<std::string, std::string> mappify2(std::string const& s)
{
    std::map<std::string, std::string> m;

    std::string::size_type key_pos = 0;
    std::string::size_type key_end;
    std::string::size_type val_pos;
    std::string::size_type val_end;

    while((key_end = s.find(':', key_pos)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        if((val_pos = s.find_first_not_of(": ", key_end)) == std::string::npos)
            break;

        if((val_end = s.find('\n', val_pos)) == std::string::npos)
            val_end = s.size();

        m.emplace(s.substr(key_pos, key_end - key_pos), s.substr(val_pos, val_end - val_pos));

        key_pos = val_end + 1;

        if(val_end == s.size())
            break;
    }

    return m;
}
 
int main()
{
    std::string s = "CA: ABCD\nCB: ABFG\nCC: AFBV\nCD: 4567";

    std::cout << "mappify1: " << '\n';

    auto m = mappify1(s);
    for(auto const& p: m)
        std::cout << '{' << p.first << " => " << p.second << '}' << '\n';

    std::cout << "mappify2: " << '\n';

    m = mappify2(s);
    for(auto const& p: m)
        std::cout << '{' << p.first << " => " << p.second << '}' << '\n';
}
```

**Output:**

```
mappify1: 
{CA => ABCD}
{CB => ABFG}
{CC => AFBV}
{CD => 4567}
mappify2: 
{CA => ABCD}
{CB => ABFG}
{CC => AFBV}
{CD => 4567}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I think your solution2 has an issue in that the delimiter might end up in the value,

Answer (score 2):

This format is called "Tag-Value".

The most performance critical place where such encoding is used in the industry is probably financial FIX Protocol (`=` for key-value separator, and `'\001'` as entries delimiter). So if you are on x86 hardware then your best bet would be to google 'SSE4 FIX protocol parser github' and reuse the open sourced findings of HFT shops.

If you still want to delegate the vectorization part to the compiler and can spare few nanoseconds for readability then the most elegant solution is to store the result in a `std::string` (data) + `boost::flat_map<boost::string_ref, boost::string_ref>` (view). Parsing is a matter of taste, while-loop or strtok would be easiest for the compiler to parse. Boost-spirit based parser would be easiest for a human (familiar with boost-spirit) to read.

**C++ for-loop based solution**

```
#include <boost/container/flat_map.hpp> 
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>

#include <boost/range/iterator_range_io.hpp> 
#include <iostream>

// g++ -std=c++1z ~/aaa.cc
int main()
{
    using range_t = boost::iterator_range<std::string::const_iterator>;
    using map_t = boost::container::flat_map<range_t, range_t>;

    char const sep = ':';
    char const dlm = '\n';

    // this part can be reused for parsing multiple records
    map_t result;
    result.reserve(1024);

    std::string const input {"hello:world\n bye: world"};

    // this part is per-line/per-record
    result.clear();
    for (auto _beg = begin(input), _end = end(input), it = _beg; it != _end;)
    {
        auto sep_it = std::find(it, _end, sep);
        if (sep_it != _end)
        {
            auto dlm_it = std::find(sep_it + 1, _end, dlm);
            result.emplace(range_t {it, sep_it}, range_t {sep_it + 1, dlm_it});
            it = dlm_it + (dlm_it != _end);
        }
        else throw std::runtime_error("cannot parse");
    }

    for (auto& x: result)
        std::cout << x.first << " => " << x.second << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using a parser generator (and specifically the `boost::spirit` monstrosity) to parse a tag-value string is definitely overkill...

Comment: @MatteoItalia - totally, a while loop will be the most natural way of doing it, and this is how it would be done in most github FIX protocol parsers, which I suggested to look at.

Answer (score 1):

The format is simple enough that doing the parsing "by hand" IMO is the best option, overall remains quite readable.

This should also be reasonably efficient (the `key` and `value` strings are always the same - albeit `clear`ed, so the reallocations inside the main loop should just stop after a few iterations); `ret` also should qualify for NRVO, OTOH in case of problems with that you can always change to an output parameter.

Of course `std::map` may not be the fastest gun in the west, but it's a request in the problem text.

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> parseKV(const std::string &sz) {
    std::map<std::string, std::string> ret;
    std::string key;
    std::string value;
    const char *s=sz.c_str();
    while(*s) {
        // parse the key
        while(*s && *s!=':' && s[1]!=' ') {
            key.push_back(*s);
            ++s;
        }
        // if we quit due to the end of the string exit now
        if(!*s) break;
        // skip the ": "
        s+=2;
        // parse the value
        while(*s && *s!='\n') {
            value.push_back(*s);
            ++s;
        }
        ret[key]=value;
        key.clear(); value.clear();
        // skip the newline
        ++s;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If worried about performance, you should probably rethink the need for the end result to be a map. That could end up being a lot of char buffers in memory. Ideally keeping track of just the char* and length of each sub string will be faster/smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, using `strtok` as a splitting means. Please note that `strtok` changes your string, it puts '\0' at the split char.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;



int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char s1[] = "CA: ABCD\nCB: ABFG\nCC: AFBV\nCD: 4567";
    map<string, string> mymap;
    char *token;

    token = strtok(s1, "\n");
    while (token != NULL) {
        string s(token);
        size_t pos = s.find(":");
        mymap[s.substr(0, pos)] = s.substr(pos + 1, string::npos);
        token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    }

    for (auto keyval : mymap) 
        cout << keyval.first << "/" << keyval.second << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::map` without custom allocator is the best tool to slow down the code (memory allocations) and fragment the heap on the way.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you should worry about optimization for reading this string and converting it in a `std::map`. If you really want to optimize this fixed-content map, change it to a `std::vector<std::pair<>>` and sort it once.

That said, the most elegant way of creating the `std::map` with standard C++ features is the following:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> deserializeKeyValue(const std::string &sz) {
    constexpr auto ELEMENT_SEPARATOR = ": "s;
    constexpr auto LINE_SEPARATOR = "\n"s;

    std::map<std::string, std::string> result;
    std::size_t begin{0};
    std::size_t end{0};
    while (begin < sz.size()) {
        // Search key
        end = sz.find(ELEMENT_SEPARATOR, begin);
        assert(end != std::string::npos); // Replace by error handling
        auto key = sz.substr(begin, /*size=*/ end - begin);
        begin = end + ELEMENT_SEPARATOR.size();

        // Seach value
        end = sz.find(LINE_SEPARATOR, begin);
        auto value = sz.substr(begin, end == std::string::npos ? std::string::npos : /*size=*/ end - begin);
        begin = (end == std::string::npos) ? sz.size() : end + LINE_SEPARATOR.size();

        // Store key-value
        [[maybe_unused]] auto emplaceResult = result.emplace(std::move(key), std::move(value));
        assert(emplaceResult.second); // Replace by error handling
    }
    return result;
}
```

The performance of this might not be ideal, though every c++ programmer understands this code.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution using boost is the following, it works also with partial tokens (e.g. key without values or empty pairs).

```
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main() {

    string s = "CA: ABCD\nCB: ABFG\nCC: AFBV\nCD: 4567";

    list<string> tokenList;
    split(tokenList,s,is_any_of("\n"),token_compress_on);
    map<string, string> kvMap;

    BOOST_FOREACH(string token, tokenList) {
        size_t sep_pos = token.find_first_of(": ");
        string key = token.substr(0,sep_pos);
        string value = (sep_pos == string::npos ? "" : token.substr(sep_pos+2,string::npos));
        kvMap[key] = value;

        cout << "[" << key << "] => [" << kvMap[key] << "]" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void splitString(std::map<std::string, std::string> &mymap, const std::string &text, char sep)
{
    int start = 0, end1 = 0, end2 = 0;
    while ((end1 = text.find(sep, start)) != std::string::npos && (end2 = text.find(sep, end1+1)) != std::string::npos) {
        std::string key = text.substr(start, end1 - start);
        std::string val = text.substr(end1 + 1, end2 - end1 - 1);
        mymap.insert(std::pair<std::string,std::string>(key, val));
        start = end2 + 1;
    }
}
```

For example:

```
std::string text = "key1;val1;key2;val2;key3;val3;";
std::map<std::string, std::string> mymap;
splitString(mymap, text, ';');
```

Will result in a map of size 3: { key1="val1", key2="val2", key3="val3" }

More examples:

"key1;val1;key2;"  => {key1="val1"} (no 2nd val, so 2nd key doesn't count)

"key1;val1;key2;val2"  => {key1="val1"}  (no delim at end of the 2nd val, so it doesn't count)

"key1;val1;key2;;" => {key1="val1",key2=""} (key2 holds empty string)

Answer (score 0):

Have looked through the accepted answer and tried to extend a bit which seems to work in more general cases. The test run can be found [here](https://ideone.com/KKvcqf). All kind of comments or modification are welcome.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

size_t find(const std::string& line, std::vector<std::string> vect, int pos=0) {
    int eol1;
    eol1 = 0;
    for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator iter = vect.begin(); iter != vect.end(); ++iter) {
        //std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
        int eol2 = line.find(*iter, pos);
        if (eol1 == 0 && eol2 > 0)
            eol1 = eol2;
        else if (eol2 > 0 && eol2 < eol1)
            eol1 = eol2;
    }
    return eol1;
}

std::map<std::string, std::string> mappify(std::string const& s, char delim='=') {
    std::map<std::string, std::string> m;

    std::string::size_type key_pos = 0, i, j;
    std::string::size_type key_end;
    std::string::size_type val_pos;
    std::string::size_type lim_pos;
    std::string::size_type val_end;

    while ((key_end = s.find(delim, key_pos)) != std::string::npos) {
        if ((val_pos = s.find_first_not_of(delim, key_end + 1)) == std::string::npos)break;
        while (key_end - 1 > 0 && (s[key_end - 1] <= 32 || s[key_end - 1] == ';'))
            key_end--;
        while (val_pos < s.size() && (s[val_pos] <= 32 || s[val_pos] == ';'))
            val_pos++;
        val_end = s.find('\n', val_pos);
        i = s.find('\"', val_pos);
        if (i != std::string::npos)
            j = s.find('\"', i + 1);
        else
            j = 0;
        lim_pos = find(s.substr(0, i), { " ",";","\t" }, val_pos + 1);
        //std::cout << "s.substr(j):" << s.substr(j)<<std::endl;
        if (lim_pos == 0 && j != std::string::npos)lim_pos = find(s.substr(j), { " ",";","\t" }) + j;
        if (lim_pos < val_pos)lim_pos = val_pos + 1;
        if (j > 0)val_end = j + 1;
        if (val_end > lim_pos)val_end = lim_pos;
        m.emplace(s.substr(key_pos, key_end - key_pos), s.substr(val_pos, val_end - val_pos));
        key_pos = val_end;
        while ((key_pos < s.size() && s[key_pos] <= 32 || s[key_pos] == ';'))
            ++key_pos;
        if (val_end == 0)break;
    }
    return m;
}

int main() {
    std::string s ="\
File=\"c:\\dir\\ocean\\\nCCS_test.txt\"\n\
iEcho=10000; iHrShift=0 rho_Co2 = 1.15d0;\n\
Liner=01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890";
  auto m = mappify(s);
    for (auto const& p : m)
      std::cout << '{' << p.first << " :=> " << p.second << '}' << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```