# Split a string into a vector<string> by multiple string delimiters

Tags: c++, string, split

In C++, without using any `boost` routines, we know how to:

- [split a string by a single char value or multiple char values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621727/split-a-string-into-words-by-multiple-delimiters)
- split a string by a single string value:

  ```
  void ParseStringByStringSeparator(string s, const string separator, vector<string>& result)
  {
      result.clear();
      size_t pos = 0;
      string token;

      while ((pos = s.find(separator)) != string::npos) {
          token = s.substr(0, pos);
          result.push_back(token);
          s.erase(0, pos + separator.length());
      }
      result.push_back(s);
  }
  ```

But how to split a string by multiple string values?

For example, If I have the following string value `"Hello I am a String"` and my separators are `" "` and `"am"` then I would like to obtain the following `vector<string>` value:

```
{"Hello","I","a","String"}
```

Any hint?

Comment: Split string using first delimiter, then split result using second delimiter.

Comment: Do a find and replace of all the other delimiters into the first one and the split using the first delimiter?

Comment: That would work, but it could fail if the first delimiter was not a single character - because as the words are replaced it could inadvertently create another delimiter in the string.

Comment: The more I think about the more I think  ikleschenkov is correct.  Split the string using the first delimiter, then split each sub string by the next one and repeat that for each next one.

Comment: What to do if a delimiter contains other delimiters? largest wins?

Answer (score 0):

This function do what you want to do. It basically iterate on the vector of delimiters, applying your function for each one :

```cpp
vector<string> SplitStringMultipleStrParameters(string s,const vector<string>& separators) {

    //The result to be returned
    vector<string> result = { s };

    //Iterate on the list of separators, so for each separators
    for (const auto& sep : separators) {
        //toReplaceBy will be the next vector of strings where it will iterate
        vector<string> toReplaceBy, tempRes;

        //For each strings, we will split on "sep", the separator
        for (auto&a : result) {
            //Because of the result vector being cleared every time your function get called
            //It get in a temp vector that we will concatenate after
            ParseStringByStringSeparator(a, sep, tempRes);
            //Concatenation of theses vectors
            toReplaceBy.insert(toReplaceBy.end(), tempRes.begin(), tempRes.end());
        }

        //Erasing all strings that are empty. C++11 code here required because of the lambda
        toReplaceBy.erase(std::remove_if(toReplaceBy.begin(), toReplaceBy.end(),
            [](const std::string& i) {
            return i == "";
        }), toReplaceBy.end());

        //The vector containing strings to be splited is replaced by the split result on this iteration
        result = toReplaceBy;
        //And we will split those results using the next separator, if there's more separator to iterate on
    }
    return result;
}
```

Code to test :

```cpp
string test = "Hello I am a string";

auto r = SplitStringMultipleStrParameters(test, { " ", "am" });

for (auto& a : r) {
    std::cout << a << '\n';
}
```

It needs to be compiled with a C++11 compiler, and need to include the `<algorithm>` header.

If your compiler does not compile C++11 code, here is the function :

```cpp
vector<string> SplitStringMultipleStrParameters(string s,const vector<string>& separators) {
    vector<string> result = { s };
    for (const auto& sep : separators) {
        vector<string> toReplaceBy, tempRes;
        for (auto&a : result) {
            ParseStringByStringSeparator(a, sep, tempRes);
            toReplaceBy.insert(toReplaceBy.end(), tempRes.begin(), tempRes.end());
        }
        auto it = toReplaceBy.begin();
        while (it != toReplaceBy.end()) {
            if ((*it) == "")
                it = toReplaceBy.erase(it);
            else
                ++it;
        }
        result = toReplaceBy;
    }
    return result;
}
```