# How to split a line of text by tabs in C++?

Tags: c++

I am a C++ beginner, and recently my professor assigned a C++ homework that in my opinion, is hard to solve using C++. Below is the problem:

**Problem Statement**
Given a file, whose content is a table in which cells are separated by
a tab. For instance:

```
Full Name    Age    Gender
Cliff Chiang    9    B
Olivia Yang    8    G
```

For each line, split the line by a tab (For the above, the result is `["Cliff Chiang", 9, 8]` and `["Olivia Yang", 8, 6]`).

**Associated questions**

- [Read file line by line using ifstream in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line-using-ifstream-in-c)

- [How can I read and parse CSV files in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c)

The first question doesn't really answer my question since my problem is to split a string by tabs, not a newline. Plus, there might be spaces in my table, which is not a question the problem above fully solved.

The second question converts in CSV format, not what mine is.

**My question**

- Is there any appreciated solution to this problem using C++?
- If not, is there a simple function that could do that?
  Thanks for your help.

Comment: The linked "duplicate" does not answer this question. @user4581301

Comment: f.y.i. here is a better answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/7621727/7098259

Comment: Replaced duplicate. General gist: `std::getline` to get line. Feed line into `std::stringstream`. Use `std::getline` on stream to tab-delimited tokens.