# Define own unicode locale

Tags: c++, unicode, locale

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4888916/4790099) great solution of counting words in text. My problem is I can properly understand these "magic" of STL that the solution provide. If I understand right letter_only - is a struct that create locale object to find only letters and excluding punctuaion. When main() calls imbue() letter_only's constructor calls get_table()... Realization of this function for me - deep dark magic.

I spend a lot of time to read cppreference but can't exactly understand those 3 strings.

My goal is adapting this solution to unicode chars.

Can someone explain me how it works? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A locale is not a simple object; it's built from multiple *facets*. One of those facets is the `ctype`. (Character type). Your linked solution creates a locale with a custom `ctype<char>` called `letter_only`.

The implementation of `letter_only` works by building a table of characters, so you can determine if `char c` is a letter by lookup.

This is potentially different for you, as a table for `wchar_t` would be much bigger. That's why when inheriting from `ctype<wchar_t>` you typically override `virtual bool do_is(mask m, wchar_t c) const`.

Comment: Thank you. Am I right that std::fill - just filling vector (rc) with "english" characters so creating the "table"?

Comment: No, that's not how the lookup table works. The "english" characters are not the content, but the table _index_. The table content is their type (`alpha` = alphabetic).

Comment: There is a clue) Thank you