# What would the C++ equivalent of this C input be?

Tags: c++

How would I implement this line in C++

```
scanf("%lf, %lf, %lf", &a, &b, &c)
```

ie: I want to get file data input that is separated by commas

Comment: `scanf()` reads from STDIN.  To read from a file, you would have had to use `fscanf()` instead.

Comment: I just normally input the file from the command prompt

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1:**

```
std::cin >> a;
std::cin.ignore();
std::cin >> b;
std::cin.ignore();
std::cin >> c;
```

[`ignore()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/) ignores a single character.

**Solution 2:**

Use a dummy variable for the comma:

```
char comma;
std::cin >> a >> comma >> b >> comma >> c;
```

Comment: Is there a much easier way or should is it easier to use scanf

Comment: I agree it's more elegant with `scanf`... C++ i/o is a bit clumsy.

Answer (score 0):

```
char comma1, comma2;
if (file_stream >> a >> comma1 >> b >> comma2 >> c &&
    comma1 == ',' && comma2 == ',')
    ...a b and c read & parsed successfully...
else
    ...error...
```

---

Remy Lebeau comments below that he thinks the functionally equivalent code below is easier for beginners to understand - I disagree but readers can make up their own mind:

```
char comma1, comma2;
file_stream >> a >> comma1 >> b >> comma2 >> c;
if (!file_stream.fail() && (comma1 == ',') && (comma2 == ','))
    ...a b and c read & parsed successfully...
else
    ...error...
```

---

If your "file data" is arriving on `stdin` as you've indicated in a comment, you can replace `file_stream` above with `std::cin`.  If you want to use an actual file stream:

```
if (std::ifstream file_stream(filename))
    if (file_stream >> a >> ...as above...
```

---

Alternatively, [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988622/c-string-parsing-ideas/4988768#4988768) codes up a `Str` class that allows usage like this:

```
if (file_stream >> a >> Str(",") >> b >> Str(",") >> c)
    ...a b and c read & parsed succesfully...
```

Comment: @RemyLebeau: sorry - I consider your edit a style choice I happen to disagree with - have reverted.  Proof it works just fine as posted [here](http://ideone.com/F5yTY2).  Cheers.

Comment: You misspelled `cooma2` in the last condition of the `if`statement.  And the extra parenthesis make it clearer which conditions are actually being checked, especially around the `file_stream` operators, that the `file_stream` itself (which is the result of the last `>>` operator in the chain) is what is being checked for success/fail.  And since the OP is clearly a novice, clearer code is better to learn from.  I would probably break the `>>` operators out of the `if` statement: `file_stream >> a >> comma1 >> b >> comma2 >> c; if (!file_stream.fail() && (comma1 == ',') && (comma2 == ',')) ...`

Comment: @RemyLebeau: sure - comment appreciated for readers' sake, and I'll add in your preferred style as an option for their consideration - they can make their own choice.

Answer (score -2):

Do you want to read data from file instead of standard stream?
Then use [fscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/)

Comment: `fscanf()` is C.  The question asked for C++.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I don't know what broken C++ compiler you're using... the Standard requires `fscanf`.

Comment: AFAIK, the C++ standard only requires that `fscanf()` and other C functions be wrapped in the `std` namespace, not that they actually be present.  In any case, `std::fscanf()` would still not be the "C++ way" of parsing a formatted file.  `std::(i)fstream` would be.