# Profiling a C program under CentOS Linux

Tags: profiling, centos

Under CentOS what commandline will profile my C program including the time spent in system calls? What programs do I need to install with yum?

Comment: You can use [oprofile](http://linux.die.net/man/1/oprofile).

Comment: Or you can use [perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial) (`yum install perf` in CentOS6)

Comment: I have a solution for your regex to C question. See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505210/convert-compile-regular-expressions-to-c-code

Answer (score 1):

Install oprofile: `yum install oprofile`

Initialize oprofile:

```
opcontrol --no-vmlinux #If you have vmlinux set this option differently
opcontrol --init
opcontrol --reset
opcontrol --separate=lib
opcontrol --callgraph=0    # clear callgraph in case it was used recently
opcontrol --start
```

Now run the program to be profiled. Once it has run long enough, do the following:

```
opcontrol --dump
opreport --symbols /path/to/executable
```

See [here](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/examples/) for some other example outputs.