# How to find characters that cannot be part of a word in a Unicode string?

Tags: c++, unicode

I have some text in a string, I need to check whether that particular string contains any characters which are not allowed to make a word.

Suppose I have text like "(hello}"

Here it contains to symbols '(' and '}'. How could I do it in C++. And a string may contains any unicode character.

Comment: what are the characters that are "allowed to make a word"? just letters? numbers? underscore? space? punctuation marks? for just letters see [`isalpha`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/isalpha/) or [`iswalpha`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/iswalpha.html).

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: Either I did not get your question correctly, or you are looking for regular expressions in C++. If that is true, look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181624/c-what-regex-library-should-i-use?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: boost::regex, libpcre, or just simple strspn/strcspn, strpbrk...

Comment: Can you elaborate further on which characters "are allowed to make a word"?

Comment: Nope I don't wants regex. I just need to find a way to get whether this character is valid for making any word or not.

Comment: "petróleo" this is valid spanish word. if I use isalpha or iswalpha then it fails here for "ó" character.

Comment: @dearvivekkumar If you use a Spanish locale, then `std::isalpha` should work properly. Are you really trying to see if something is a word *in any language at all*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the string really contains Unicode (UTF-8), the problem is decidedly
non-trivial; you'll probably want to use some external library, like
ICU.  Or you can convert to `wchar_t` (`wstring`), and use the single
byte encoding solution below:

If the characters are single byte encoded, `std::find_if` with a
suitable predicate should do the trick.  If you're doing any text
parsing, you'll want to define as set of such predicates, once and for
all; the predicates can use the functions in the `std::ctype` facet of 
`locale`, or the ones in `wctype.h` (which use the global locale).

Still, if you are dealing with Unicode, even converting to wide
characters may not be enough, since full Unicode can still use more than
one code point to represent a single character.  The real question is
just how serious you want to do this.  (Note too that in many languages,
like English or French, "words" can contain characters which Unicode
considers punctuation, e.g. "don't" or "aujourd'hui"—the Unicode
tables will tell you that `'\''` is punctuation, not part of a word.)

Comment: May be I am not explaining  my need correctly. I have to parse a file to make word from that. that word can be in any language. i have checked for space for separating words from the text. But that does not seem to be sufficient. As suppose I have a text like "my name (vivek " then here i to three words my, name and vivek. I need to some general solution to this. I need idea how to handle this things.

Comment: Well, the biggest problem is to define what characters can or cannot be in a word.  Do you accept "don't" as a word?  Then you'll have to add some special case to your predicate.  Do you accept an 'x' with a circumflex accent in a word?  If so, even with wide characters, you'll have to handle multicode sequences (so you can't use `find_if`.  The same thing holds if you can't guarantee a specific canonized format in your input.

Answer (score 1):

`std::isalpha` (and related `is*` friends) are templated on the character type AND accept a locale to allow better localization ability too. I would just iterate over the `string` or `wstring` and use the `is*` function(s) that indicate the behavior you're interested in (I can't tell which characters you want to allow and disallow from the problem statement).

Comment: For basic purposes, that would be my recommendation, too. For hardcore no-scripts-barred Unicode processing something like ICU would probably be better, but it totally depends on your situation. Locale-aware regexes sound pretty sexy.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::wstring` and `std::iswalpha()`.