# Having a pair<string, string> how to find if its part of some pair in map<string, string>?

Tags: c++, search, stdmap, std-pair

We have a pair of strings for example such pair `Accept-Language : RU ,` and we search thru map, for example of http request headers. All we ned to know if there is such pair in map or not - a bool value. How to do to a soft search meaning we do not need to find exact same pair but pair like `Accept-Language : ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4` is also a valid pair for us and if such exists we can think we have found that our map contains our pair. How to make a function for performing such search in C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you are using a `map`, you cannot have multiple entries with the same key. E.g. you can't have both `Accept-Language : RU` and `Accept-Language : ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4` because they have the same key `Accept-Language'. Perhaps in your case you should use a vector of pairs, or a multimap.

Next, your question consists of 2 parts:

1. How to check, whether some element (such as `string` or `pair`)
   matches a pattern.
2. Assuming you have
   such a check, how to apply it to
   each element in a container.

The solutions to each part:

1. You can implement a function that takes a `string`, or a `pair` (depends on the type of container and stored element that you choose), and checks whether it matches your criteria. You can find the functions such as [string::find_first_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/) to be useful for that matter. The [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181624/c-what-regex-library-should-i-use) libraries can be even more helpful, though they are not part of the STL.
2. You can apply this function on every element of your container using [find_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/) algorithm.