# How to remove unwanted content from string in c++?

Tags: c++, linux

Hi I have a string variable with large content. 
I have to remove unwanted line from the string content and keep remaining content as it is.
Following is output that we get after printing the string:

```
string varString;
cout<<"String content :"<<endl<<varString<<endl;

Output is :
String content :
/abc/def/ghi/klm/run.so
call::myFuncton(int const&)
call::MY::Method(char const&)
.
.
.
call::MY::newFunction(char *&)
```

Now i have to remove "call::myFuncton(int const&)" line from above string variable and keep other data as it is. 
can any one tell tell me how i can remove that line from sting variable?
Thanks in advance

Comment: can we remove the single line completly, separated by "\n" character ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function varString.[find()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) to find the position where the string occurs, and then use varString.[erase()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/) to erase the text.

Answer (score 1):

You first **[find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)** the string then you **[erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/)** it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex to replace the required string **call::myFuncton(int const&)** using Regex. You can find more information about using Regex in C++ from this link [C++: what regex library should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181624/c-what-regex-library-should-i-use)

Comment: This approach is beneficial if you intend to remove all **call:Func(param)** strings from your single big block of string, otherwise [find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) and [erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/) should work out pretty well.