# Is there a better way to parse a line of text like this?

Tags: c++, string, parsing

I have a text file with lines of text that have a string another string followed by up to 4 integers,
ex:

```
clear "clear water.png" 5 7
wet "wet water.png" 9 5 33 17
soft "soft rain falling.png"
```

The only way I see it is:

> read until space is found
>
> set string to wet
>
> read until double quote
>
> read until second double quote
>
> set second string to wet water.png
>
> while not end of line
>
> read until space
>
> put string through string stream
>
> push resulting integer into vector of int

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Better in terms of logic, simplicity, performance, or what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the sort of task for which `scanf` and company truly shine.

```
char first_string[33], second_string[129];

sscanf(input_string, 
    "%32s%*[^\"]%*c%128[^\"]%*c %d %d %d %d", 
    first_string, 
    second_string, 
    &first_int, 
    &second_int,
    &third_int,
    &fourth_int);
```

You probably want to do that in an `if` statement so you can test the return value, to tell you how many of those fields converted (e.g., so you know how many integers you read at the end).

Edit: perhaps some explanation would be helpful. Let's dissect that:

%32s       reads a string to the first white-space (or 32 characters, whichever comes first).
%*[^\"]    ignores input up to the first `"`.
%*c        ignores one more byte of input (the quote itself)
%128[^\"]  reads the string in the quote (i.e., up to the next quote character).
%*c        Ignores the closing quote
%d         Reads an int (which we've done four times).

The space before each `%d` is really unnecessary -- it'll skip whitespace, but without the space, `%d` will skip leading whitespace anyway. I've included them purely to make it a little more readable.

Comment: I find that to be a great answer!

Comment: I *had* to upvote this, although I don't have a high opinion of `scanf` and it's not idiomatic C++.

Comment: @ybungalobill: what do you think is nonstandard about it? If you're thinking of the `%[^\"]`, you're mistaken -- that's a scanset conversion which is part of standard C. It isn't new either -- although not in K&R1, it's been in the standard from the beginning because by then it was already widespread.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Hmm, don't have the C89 standard, but as per C99 you're right. Didn't know this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ugly, with no error-checking, but no dependencies on any non-standard libraries:

```
string s;
while(getline(fin, s))
{
    string word, quoted_string;
    vector<int> vec;

    istringstream line(s);
    line >> word;
    line.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '"');
    getline(line, quoted_string, '"');
    int n;
    while(line >> n) vec.push_back(n);

    // do something with word, quoted_string and vec...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the restrictions of the input strings you could trying splitting on `double-quote` then splitting on `space`.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**

Use `getline` to read one line at a time.  Parse the lines using [a regular expression library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181624/c-what-regex-library-should-i-use).