# Why does this C++11 std::regex example throw a regex_error exception?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, g++

Trying to learn how to use the new std::regex in C++11.  But the example I tried is throwing a regex_error exception I don't understand.  Here is my sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "xyzabc1xyzabc2xyzabc3abc4xyz";
    std::regex re( "(abc[1234])" ); // <-- this line throws a C++ exception

    // also tried to do this:
    // std::regex re( "(abc[1234])", std::regex::optimize | std::regex::extended );

    while ( true )
    {
        std::cout << "searching in " << str << std::endl;
        std::smatch match;
        std::regex_search( str, match, re );
        if ( match.empty() )
        {
            std::cout << "...no more matches" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        for ( auto x : match )
        {
            std::cout << "found: " << x << std::endl;
        }
        str = match.suffix().str();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I compile and run like this:

```
g++ -g -std=c++11 test.cpp
./a.out
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
  what():  regex_error
```

Looking at the backtrace in gdb, I see the exception thrown is `regex_constants::error_brack`.

Comment: [g++ libstdc++ does not support std::regex](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x)

Comment: What version of gcc are you using?

Comment: @JamesEldridge Doesn't matter what version, even 4.8.0 doesn't support std::regex

Comment: @Praetorian Yes you are right, current status is N: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html

Comment: There is always boost regex: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the hint.  Had no idea the regex code in g++ was incomplete.

In the meantime, guess we'll have to refer to this old StackOverflow question:

[C++: what regex library should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181624/c-what-regex-library-should-i-use)

Comment: First gcc support is in gcc 4.9 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23474121/what-part-of-regex-is-supported-by-gcc-4-9