# Regex in C++11 vs PHP

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I'm new to regex and C++11. In order to match an expression like this :

`TYPE SIZE NUMBER ("regina s x99");`

I built a regex which looks like this one :

`\b(regina|margarita|americaine|fantasia)\b \b(s|l|m|xl|xxl)\b x([1-9])([0-9])`

In my code I did this to try the regex :

```
std::string s("regina s x99");
std::regex rgx($RGX); //$RGX corresponds to the regex above
if (std::regex_match(s, rgx))
std::cout << "It works !" << std::endl;
```

This code throw a `std::regex_error`, but I don't know where it comes from..

Thanks,

Comment: Use GCC 4.9.0: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671536/why-does-this-c11-stdregex-example-throw-a-regex-error-exception

Comment: @Nicolas why there is PHP reference in subject line?

Comment: @stribizhev I'm compiling with g++-4.9 and still the same error.

Comment: @Steephen I thought maybe the regex patern was a bit different between those two languages.

Comment: @NicolasCharvozKurzawa This works fine in gcc 4.9.2: http://ideone.com/REkhzI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with g++ (4.9.2) in c++11 mode:

```
std::regex rgx("\\b(regina|margarita|americaine|fantasia)\\b\\s*(s|l|m|xl|xxl)\\b\\s*x([1-9]*[0-9])");
```

This will capture three groups: **regina s 99** which matches the TYPE SIZE NUMBER pattern, while your original captured four groups **regina s 9 9** and had the NUMBER as two values (maybe that was what you wanted though).

[Demo on IdeOne](http://ideone.com/C773YV)

Comment: The last group can (and probably should) be tweaked a bit depending on the range of the NUMBER you want to match (if it has a leading 0 or not. Maybe it should be `x([1-9]+[0-9]*)` for `1 to N`

Answer (score 1):

In C++ strings the `\` character is special and needs to be escaped so that it gets passed to the regular expression engine, not interpreted by the compiler.

So you either need to use `\\b`:

```
std::regex rgx("\\b(regina|margarita|americaine|fantasia)\\b \\b(s|l|m|xl|xxl)\\b x([1-9])([0-9])");
```

or use a raw string, which means that `\` is not special and doesn't need to be escaped:

```
 std::regex rgx(R"(\b(regina|margarita|americaine|fantasia)\b \b(s|l|m|xl|xxl)\b x([1-9])([0-9]))");
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo in  this line in **original** question:

```
if (std::reegex_match(s, rgx))
```

More over I am not sure what are you passing with this variable : `$RGX`

Corrected program as follows:

```
#include<regex>
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    std::string s("regina s x99");
std::regex rgx("\\b(regina|margarita|americaine|fantasia)\\b \\s*(s|l|m|xl|xxl)\\b \\s*x([1-9])([0-9])"); //$RGX corresponds to the regex above
if (std::regex_match(s, rgx))
std::cout << "It works !" << std::endl;
else
  std::cout<<"No Match"<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Yeah copy/paste does not work between VMWare and MAC Os X, there is no typo in my code, and the variable $RGX does not exist in my code, I didn't want to rewrite the regex again. I thought it was clearer this way.

Comment: @Steephen You need to escape your slashes or this will never match.

Comment: @Jonathan Mee I was just using the pattern he tried, I will correct it

Comment: @JonathanMee corercted it is matching now

Comment: @Steephen, since the OP said he gets a `regex_error` I think it's safe to assume the code compiled, and so there's no typo in the original. Also, you apparently didn't test your corrected code, it still doesn't match.

Comment: @JonathanWakely There was a typo, he corrected after see the answer!!  I tested the code after correction before posting and it works

Comment: I know there was a typo in **the question** but that obviously wasn't the cause of the `regex_error` exception.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I didn't mean typo is the reason for regex_error