# How to arrange the loops to check for numbers

Tags: c++, cstring, ctype

I have a program that reads a credit card number. I want to add in something that makes sure that 16 numbers are added in, no letters, and as many spaces as wanted (although they don't count towards numbers). Is there a function or set of functions to do this, or should I just make a bunch of while and if loops that use isdigit() and isalpha() that goes through the array one element at a time?

```
char cardNum[32];
cout << "Enter credit card number: ";
cin.getline(cardNum, 32); //Read in the entire line for the name
```

Comment: Well you wouldn't need a bunch of while loops if you wanted to do it that way. One while loop would suffice. But there is a better to do what you want, look into [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous things you could do. One idea is to use `std::find_if` with a custom predicate. For example:

```
bool IsCharIllegal(char ch)
{
  // return true or false based on whatever your exact requirements are
}
```

Then:

```
auto itFound = std::find_if(cardNum, cardNum + 32, IsCharIllegal);
if(itFound != cardNum + 32)
   // invalid character was entered!
```

There is a case to be made for using `std::string` instead of a raw `char` array too:

```
std::string cardNum;
cout << "Enter credit card number: ";
std::cin >> cardNum;
```

Followed by:

```
auto itFound = std::find_if(cardNum.begin(), cardNum.end(), IsCharIllegal);
if(itFound != cardNum.end())
   // invalid character was entered!
```

That helps avoid the magic `32` and also allows inputs of any length.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regular expression to match this pattern. If you're using C++11, you can use the built in  header: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/

Otherwise, take a look here for some alternative libraries you can use: [C++: what regex library should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181624/c-what-regex-library-should-i-use)

Unfortunately, I'm not very good at regular expressions, but the following should match 16 numbers with spaces inbetween.

```
(\d[ ]*){16}
```

If you're looking for more info on regular expressions, here is a good cheat sheet I use often: http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx

I also like to test my expressions using this site: http://regexpal.com/

Comment: Now we have two problems.

Comment: Updated with a better expression

Answer (score 1):

So something like this would be allowed?

```
"123  456  789 01     23456"
```

Use `std::string` and the free-standing `std::getline` function. It's better than the member function of the same name, because it doesn't force you to deal with pointers.

```
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
if (!std::cin)
{
  // catastrophic input failure
}
```

Then you have a string as in my example above in `line`. You could use `std::find_if` to verify that there are no illegal characters and `std::count_if` to make sure there are exactly 16 digits, but I think writing your own loop (not "bunch of loops") would yield more readable code here.

By the way, **beware of `isdigit`!** For historical reasons, you must cast its argument to `unsigned char` in order to use it safely.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `atoll` function in the `cstdlib`. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoll/

It converts character string input into a `long long`, which could store a 16 digit long credit card number, however this quits as soon as there's an non-numeric character in the input so

```
atoll("123456abc890")
```

would return `123456`

If you want to check each character by character, you could just use `atoi` on each character then reassemble the string for each character that passes.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

Comment: `atoi` is broken. It will return 0 for both "0" and "x".

Comment: @ChristianHackl I guess you can't read documentations. "If the first sequence of non-whitespace characters in str is not a valid integral number, or if no such sequence exists because either str is empty or it contains only whitespace characters, no conversion is performed and zero is returned."

Comment: "x" is the "the first sequence of non-whitespace characters" in the string. How does this contradict my comment? It supports it. You should really not offend other people like this.

Comment: And you should cite things you quote, by the way. Here is the source of your quote: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/